# How to save login status in express-session

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

This is my code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const compression = require('compression')

const sessionOptions = {
  secret: '123',
  name: 'test',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  rolling: true,
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000 * 1800, // 30min
    secure: true
  }
}

const app = express()
app.use(session(sessionOptions))
app.use(compression())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session)
  res.json({
    id: req.sessionID,
    data: req.session.data
  })
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  req.session.data = 'asdasdasdasd'
  res.end(req.sessionID)
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000`)
})
```

Then I visited `/` and kept refreshing the page, but each time the 'sessionID' was different.
When I first access `/login` and then access `/`, the result is:

```json
{
    "id": "8Z9bb5B6lATMe1sAIT_8QgY07YvOlr8P"
}
```

The output of the server is:

```js
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-12-28T06:35:36.057Z,
    originalMaxAge: 1800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  }
}
```

I checked the network panel of the browser console and found that the `Set-Cookie` field never appeared in the response header, even though I modified `req.session` on the server side.

I just want to implement the function of using session to record user login status.
Did I write something wrong somewhere? Humbly seeking advice, greatly appreciated!

I checked the server console output, browser developer tool request messages, and using Wireshark to crawl HTTP request messages. I hope someone can tell me the correct usage of `express-session`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question, it makes me laugh heartily. In the configuration of the `express-session` middleware, ***I set the value of `sessionOptions.cookie.secure` to `true`, which means only when I have to use HTTPS.***